# spark scala : Convert DataFrame OR Dataset to single comma separated string

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Below is the spark  scala code which will print one column DataSet[Row]:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Row, SparkSession}
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("Spark DataValidation")
        .config("SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION", "2").enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()

val kafkaPath:String="hdfs:///landing/APPLICATION/*"
val targetPath:String="hdfs://datacompare/3"
val pk:String = "APPLICATION_ID" 
val pkValues = spark
        .read
        .json(kafkaPath)
        .select("message.data.*")
        .select(pk)
        .distinct() 
pkValues.show()
```

**Output of about code :**

```
+--------------+
|APPLICATION_ID|
+--------------+
|           388|
|           447|
|           346|
|           861|
|           361|
|           557|
|           482|
|           518|
|           432|
|           422|
|           533|
|           733|
|           472|
|           457|
|           387|
|           394|
|           786|
|           458|
+--------------+
```

**Question :**

How to convert this dataframe to comma separated String variable ?

**Expected output :**

```
val   data:String= "388,447,346,861,361,557,482,518,432,422,533,733,472,457,387,394,786,458"
```

Please suggest how to convert DataFrame[Row] or Dataset to one String .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that's a good idea, since a dataFrame is a distributed object and can be inmense. `Collect` will bring all the data to the driver, so you should perform this kind operation carefully.

Here is what you can do with a dataFrame (two options):

```
df.select("APPLICATION_ID").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.mkString(",")
df.select("APPLICATION_ID").collect.mkString(",")
```

Result with a test dataFrame with only 3 rows:

```
String = 388,447,346
```

Edit: With DataSet you can do directly:

```
ds.collect.mkString(",")
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for quick response.  ds.collect.mkString(",") worked and found [] in the final value so replace method to remove it

Comment: no need to go to RDD API even with DataFrame (as he seems to work with spark 2), you can just omit the `.rdd` or even do `df.select("APPLICATION_ID").as[String].collect.mkString(",")`

Comment: You cannot just `.mkString(",")` escaping the cells may be required.

Comment: This works well for non streaming dataset. How can achieve something similar with streaming source for which `collect` cannot be used. More details here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62746964/spark-structured-streaming-filter-phoenix-table-by-streaming-dataset

Answer (score 0):

Use collect_list:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val data = pkValues.select(collect_list(col(pk))) // collect to one row
    .as[Array[Long]] // set encoder, so you will have strongly-typed Dataset
    .take(1)(0) // get the first row - result will be Array[Long]
    .mkString(",") // and join all values
```

However, it's quite a bad idea to perform collect or take of all rows. Instead, you may want to save pkValues somewhere with `.write`? Or make it an argument to other function, to keep distributed computing

Edit: Just noticed, that @SCouto posted other answer just after me. Collect will also be correct, with collect_list function you have one advantage - you can easily go grouping if you want and i.e. group keys to even and odd ones. It's up to you which solution you prefer, simpler with collect or one line longer, but more powerful

Comment: as he needs distinct values, you could also use `collect_set` and then remove the `distinct`. Instead of `take(1)(0)`, you can just use `first`